# "Both" vs "both of them"

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct form in the following sentences, "both" and "both of them"?

> a) "Both **of them** are unique."
>
> b) "Both are unique."

If "both" *by itself* already contains "both **of them**", so I can conclude that the first option is not correct. Isn't it?

Comment: Why do you think one of them might be incorrect?

Comment: Because if "both" is already "both **of them**" why people should use "both of them" while two words are extra without need.

Comment: Using more words than are strictly necessary isn't "incorrect".

Answer (score 5):

Either one works.  "Both" implies "Both of them."  They are interchangeable in English among native speakers.

Answer (score 3):

They can be interchangeable but it may depend on the context.

> Both of them
>
> Q: Do you want David or John to join us?
>   A: Both of them.

can imply a joining or grouping together, whereas

> Both
>
> Q: Salt or pepper?
>   A: Both please.

allows them to be thought of separately.