# Which is correct? "Happy new year to both of you" or "Happy new year to you both"

Tags: word-order, determiners

Which one is correct?

> Happy new year to both **of you**.

or

> Happy new year **to you** both.

Comment: related: **1.** [“Both” vs “both of them”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111264/both-vs-both-of-them/111265#111265) **2.** [Can you use “Both” alone in this case?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24385/can-you-use-both-alone-in-this-case)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+both+of+you%2C+to+you+both&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20both%20of%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20you%20both%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4):

Both are fine, and there's really little difference between them.  Other examples:

> I'd like to take both of you to dinner to thank you for your help
>   I'd like to take you both to dinner to thank you for your help.
>
> She gave them both her blessing.
>   She gave both of them her blessing.
>
> I bid you both adieu.
>   I bid both of you adieu.

In some cases one sounds better than the other, but I think this is often what is familiar and preferred rather than related to any grammar rule.

Answer (score 1):

Although both are grammatically correct, if you check the [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/linking-words-and-expressions/both) definition for the word *both*, you will know that *both* is preferably  placed at the beginning or in the middle of the sentence. So it leads me to think that placing **both** between ***to*** and ***of*** makes the sentence sound more proper.

> Happy new year to both of you

sounds much better and more suitable.

Comment: @Mari-Lou - Correction added into my answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I would also change *the sentence* to *the sentences* in the middle line.